# idempotent rule, distributive rule, and the absorption rule

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that $p\vee(p\wedge q)=p$ follows from the idempotent rule, distributive rule, and the absorption rule $p\wedge(p\vee q)=p$.

for this question i have spent 2 hours but still don't understand where to start. help here pleas!!
can this also be an answer??    p∨(p∧q)=(p∨p)∧(p∨q)
                                        =p∧(p∨q)
                                        =p

Comment: KRISSH: Suggestion...For each question you ask, you can upvote each and every answer that you find helpful. And you can also select *one* answer (per question) to *accept*. To *accept* an answer, click on the grey $\large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. It turns green when you click on it. And *you* receive 2 reputation points each time you accept an answer. (One per question asked.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using first the idempotent rule, then the distributive rule, then the "other" absorption rule, we have
$$\eqalign{p\vee(p\wedge q)
  &=(p\wedge p)\vee(p\wedge q)\cr
  &=p\wedge(p\vee q)\cr
  &=p\ .\cr}$$